# Strange png picture when trying to output a Venn Diagram to png file using venn() from gplots

Tags: r, png, venn-diagram

I want to get my Venn Diagram as a png-file. Here is how it looks when not outputting to file:

```
library(gplots)
> x <- c("X","B")
> v <- c("X","A")
venn(list(x,v))
```

Then I get this: http://postimage.org/image/d3nbyrp5f/277b50b3/  , which looks ok.

But doing this:

```
library(gplots)
> x <- c("X","B")
> v <- c("X","A")
> png(filename="test10.png")
> venn(list(x,v))
> dev.off()
```

gives this: http://postimage.org/image/tpdywxxrp/a148b2db/ , as you can see the png file does not show a correct Venn Diagram, the circles are overlapping so that a circle is on top the other one...

Any way to overcome this strange behaviour?

EDIT:

It is solved by loading cairoDevice:

```
library(cairoDevice)
```

and then use:

```
Cairo_png(filename="test.png")
```

to output a Venn Diagram correctly with venn().

Comment: You do not say what OS you are working on, but this behavior also happens on a Mac. It does not happen with the pdf() output device. I usually create png files by opening my pdfs in Preview.app and saving as png.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a problem with transparency, you can either use a different tool for venn diagrams, or use a graphics device that supports transparency, I believe that the Cairo devices allow you to create png files and honor the transparency.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with `CairoPNG` function from the `Cairo` package

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the `bg` parameter (in `png` function) to `NA` (transparent), the default background is white.

```
library(gplots)
x <- c("X","B")
v <- c("X","A")
png("bgNA.png", bg = NA)
venn(list(x,v))
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: But I prefer the solution below, then I get a white background as well.

Comment: @Bebe I see...I just tried with the `cairoDevice` and it works fine (I usually use the `Cairo` package and it doesn't work with that package )